# Swagger client changes none nullable to nullable

Tags: c#, swagger

We are using Swagger for our contracts. Consider this simple response DTO

```
public class Result 
{
   public int SomeInt { get;set; }
}
```

On the Client the swagger generated proxy will look like

```
public class Result 
{
   public int? SomeInt { get;set; }
}
```

How can i make Swagger understand that is a none nullable?

Comment: Good question, we are looking for same.  Hoping for control over generated type.  We're coming from YAML at the moment but same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the type mapping cannot be "easily" customized but it's still doable as you can download the source code and manually update the mapping.

You can find the mapping [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/languages/AbstractCSharpCodegen.java#L98-L114)

If you would like to propose a feature to add a switch/option to support none nullable in C#, please open a ticket [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues)